# SOLRCloud in JBOSS

Tags: solr, jboss, jboss7.x, solr4, jboss-eap-6

Has anyone shared step-by-step instructions on setting up SOLR Cloud in a 2-node JBOSS cluster. I've checked other newsgroups and only found similar questions but nothing detailed in terms of a wiki page or a blog with step-by-step instructions.

Comment: do you found anything relevant about that? thanks

Comment: did you find anything on this? I have the same question

Answer (score 1):

There you go : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud%20with%20Jboss
It looks pretty simple and straightforward.